# Is there C macro for member methods?

Tags: c, class, methods, macros, function-pointers

Functions can be coupled to their referring structure by using function pointers.

```
struct string
{
    char *value;
    size_t (*size)(struct string *);
};

size_t size(struct string *this)
{
    size_t i;
for(i = 0; this->value[i] != '\0'; ++i);
return i;
}

struct string *construct()
{
    string this = (string)malloc(sizeof(struct string));
    this.size = &size;
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    struct string *s = construct();
    // ...
    s->size(s); // explicitly pass self reference
}
```

But I would like to get rid of passing the `this` pointer manually. I know that this is done implicitly in C++ when you call a method of an object. Is there a way to create a macro for this in C that works for all methods and signatures?

For example, I could think of a syntax like this.

```
s=>size(); // implicitly pass self reference
```

Please note that this is just for learning purpose. I know that it is better to just use C++ if that is possible and you'd like to use class coupling. But I'm interested of how it could be done in C.

Comment: I assume `CALL_METHOD(s, size)` is too ugly to be an improvement?

Comment: CALLMETHOD(objectref,methodname,otherargs) could do it, of course, but I can't think of any way to do it without some similar change to the appearance of the code.

Comment: @delnan Yes, I don't know if something like `#define X=>Y(Z) X->Y(X, Z)` is possible though. How much freedom do macros have to modify syntax?

Comment: @danijar C macros must be either plain identifiers (no parameters) or look like function calls. They don't need to be syntactically valid, so they are fairly flexible in some regards, but they can't do that.

Comment: @delnan Okay, I didn't know that. So this is not possible.

Comment: I mean, you *could* use C++... ;-)

Comment: @templatetypedef I do so for deployment systems, but recently I mess about with C for a lower level understanding.

Comment: Nothing forces you to use all the extra features in C++. You could write almost the same code (there are small differences) using only C features + member functions.

Comment: @immibis It was a "Is it possible?" question, not a "How to do best?" one. As I already said, only for learning purpose.

Comment: +1 for not changing to C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you're able to use the [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) feature:

```
// ...

#define CALL_METHOD(x, y, ...) x->y(x, ##__VA_ARGS__)

struct string
{
    char *value;
    size_t (*size)(struct string *);
    int (*compare)(struct string *, struct string *);
    int (*set_value)(struct string *, const char *);
};

// ...

int main()
{
    // ...

    CALL_METHOD(s1, set_value, "foo");
    CALL_METHOD(s2, set_value, "bar");

    printf("s1->size(s1) = %zu;\n", s1->size(s1));
    printf("CALL_METHOD(s1, size) = %zu;\n", CALL_METHOD(s1, size));
    printf("s1->compare(s1, s2) = %d;\n", s1->compare(s1, s2));
    printf("CALL_METHOD(s1, compare, s2) = %d;\n", CALL_METHOD(s1, compare, s2));

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can think as s->size() syntax.

If you think in multiple scopes of a function this is possible.

To GCC

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
        const char *value;
        size_t (*size)();
        void (*destroy)();
} string;

#define STRING(A)                                               \
        string *A = (string *) malloc(sizeof(string));          \
        A->value = "";                                          \
        {                                                       \
                size_t size() {                                 \
                        size_t i;                               \
                                                                \
                        for(i = 0; A->value[i] != '\0'; ++i);   \
                        return i;                               \
                }                                               \
                                                                \
                void destroy() {                                \
                        free(A);                                \
                }                                               \
                                                                \
                A->size = &size;                                \
                A->destroy = &destroy;                          \
        }

int main() {
        printf("\n=== s1 ===\n");
        STRING(s1);
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s1->size());
        s1->value = "FOOO";
        printf("%s\n", s1->value);
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s1->size());

        printf("\n=== s2 ===\n");
        STRING(s2);
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s2->size());
        s2->value = "BAZ";
        printf("%s\n", s2->value);
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s2->size());

        printf("\n=== s1 ===\n");
        s1->value="A";
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s1->size());
        printf("%s\n", s1->value);

        printf("\n=== s2 ===\n");
        s2->value="ZZ";
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s2->size());
        printf("%s\n", s2->value);

        s1->destroy();
        s2->destroy();

        return 0;
}
```

To standart C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRING(A)                                               \
        string *A = (string *) malloc(sizeof(string));          \
        A->value = "";                                          \
        A->size = &size;                                        \
        A->destroy = &destroy;

#define USE(A)                                                  \
        s = A;

typedef struct {
        const char *value;
        size_t (*size)();
        void (*destroy)();
} string;

size_t size();
void destroy();

string *s;

size_t size() {
        size_t i;

        for(i = 0; s->value[i] != '\0'; ++i);
        return i;
}

void destroy() {
        free(s);
}

int main() {
        printf("\n=== s1 ===\n");
        STRING(s1);
        USE(s1);
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s1->size());
        s1->value = "FOOO";
        printf("%s\n", s1->value);
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s1->size());

        printf("\n=== s2 ===\n");
        STRING(s2);
        USE(s2);
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s2->size());
        s2->value = "BAZ";
        printf("%s\n", s2->value);
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s2->size());

        USE(s1);
        printf("\n=== s1 ===\n");
        s1->value="A";
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s1->size());
        printf("%s\n", s1->value);

        USE(s2);
        printf("\n=== s2 ===\n");
        s2->value="ZZ";
        printf("Size: %ld\n", s2->size());
        printf("%s\n", s2->value);

        USE(s1);
        s1->destroy();

        USE(s2);
        s2->destroy();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use nested functions in standard C (though you can as a GCC extension).  Your `size` and `destroy` code would generate nested functions for `s1`.

Comment: I know that standard c not work with nested functions. But answer resolves the question. And another thing I don't understand, what's the problem with nested functions to s1?